# Strange Cart Behaviour

Tags: javascript

This is only my second project with Exp:resso, but have been a long time EE user.  I have a really strange problem, which I am hoping someone will be able to help me with.

I have a simple site, based on a template that is highly modular.  Using EE, I have placed the code for the cart into it's own template (called cart_code) and embedded it into every page on my EE site.  That way, if I need to modify the code, it's in one place.

This is fine and seems to work, and the cart code is as follows:-

```
    <div id="cart">

    {exp:store:cart}

                {if no_items}

                        <a href="" class="cart-link">
                            Shopping Cart<br /> is Empty
                    <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                        </a>
        {/if}

                {items}
                <a href="checkout" class="cart-link">Your Shopping Cart</a>
                    <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
                    <span>Items: <strong>{item_qty}</strong></span>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <span>Cost: <strong>{order_subtotal}</strong></span>
                {/items}


    {/exp:store:cart}

</div>
```

This works just fine from the home page, and if I navigate to a product page and use the "add to cart" button, the cart updates as expected.

Here is the strange part.  If I then move to an alternative product page, and click the "add to cart" button, I get my DIV (cart) rendered twice!  The first is the entry for the 1st product added, the second rendering is for the second product.

I just cannot see what I am doing wrong here.  Maybe I should change the name of the DIV ID to something less likely than "cart"?

Any help is much appreciated.  Again, all pages share the same code!!!!

Thanks, Mark.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you've got your checkout link within your `{items}` loop, so it will logically output once for each item in that loop (i.e., for each item in your cart).

Try this:

```
{if order_qty > 0}
    <a href="checkout" class="cart-link">Your Shopping Cart</a>
    <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
    <span>Items: <strong>{order_qty}</strong></span>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <span>Cost: <strong>{order_subtotal}</strong></span>
{/if}
```

Comment: Derek, doh!  I should have spotted that! Thank you and now all sorted.  Cheers, Mark.